# Why doesn't the Python 2D array index order matter when used with colon ( : )

Tags: python, python-2.x

Creating a 2D array such as

```
x = [range(i, i+10) for i in xrange(1,100,10)]
```

and indexing using the colon operator like this

```
>>> x[2][:]
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
```

works as expected. It returns all of row 2.

However, if I want to retrieve all of column 2, I would instinctively do

```
>>> x[:][2]
```

But this also returns

```
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
```

What is the reasoning behind this? I would intuitively think that this returns the column 2 of each row.

(Also, I am aware I can use numpy to do x[:,2] or I could use list comprehensions to accomplish this, that's not my question)

Comment: Print `x` and you'll understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `[:]` just means "everything", and that the two indexing operations in a row are completely independent.

```
y = x[2][:]
```

is

```
tmp = x[2]
y = tmp[:]  # this only makes a copy, does nothing else
```

Similarly,

```
y = x[:][2]
```

is

```
tmp = x[:]  # this only makes a copy, does nothing else
y = tmp[2]
```

in effect both just mean

```
y = x[2]
```

There is no 2D indexing going on at any point, Python doesn't have 2D indexing (although numpy has hacks that make *it* work like there is actual 2D indexing going on).

Answer (score 7):

`x[2][:]` will return the 3rd row of your array, and then return all elements inside that row.

`x[:][2]` will return all the rows of your array, and then return the 3rd row of them all.

Effectively, they're both the same, `x[2][:] == x[:][2]`.

Printing them in the console it's obvious why this occurs:

```
In [138]: x[2]
Out[138]: [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]

In [139]: x[2][:]
Out[139]: [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]

In [140]: x[:]
Out[140]:
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
 [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
 [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
 [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50],
 [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60],
 [61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70],
 [71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80],
 [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90],
 [91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]]

In [141]: x[:][2]
Out[141]: [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
```

If you wish to get the columns then you can effectively transpose the lists using `list(zip(*x))` (added the `list` in for Py 3). You could then do:

```
In [3]: list(zip(*x))[2]
Out[3]: (3, 13, 23, 33, 43, 53, 63, 73, 83, 93)
```

That aside, I'd suggest you use [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) instead for this kind of work.

Comment: @Kyle that's fine, but someone in the future may have the same problem but *not know about numpy* so the link is for them as much as it is for you :) similarly I added the `list` in for any future users who may be using Python 3.

Answer (score -1):

Just a note for anyone looking at this in the future.  As the others have mentioned above, `arr[:][x]` will resolve as follows.

- A temp array will be equal to `arr[:]` which is just everything.
- Then your final array will be equal to `temp[x]`

Since your first part doesn't reduce the dimensionality, the second statement will be forced to fetch a row.

In your reverse version `arr[x][:]` the following is done:

- A temp array will be equal to row x of arr
- You will then return the entire row since ":"

I know you didn't want to ask about numpy, but for others that want to know.  The numpy syntax `arr[x,:]` and `arr[:,x]` *WILL* work the way you wanted them too.  The first will grab all values in row x, and the second will grab all of the values in col x.  Do note, if you are working with a list, you will have to make a np array of it first.